# Exchange 2007 Incoming Email Body blank

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

We have Exchange 2007 (SBS 2008) which has been working without any issues for several months.

Today emails are being received, however, emails from external domains the email bodies are blank, no content at all. We are not running any email filtering software and I do not think this is a client antivirus problem, as emails are blank when viewing on OWA.

Nothing in the event logs shows anything awry. We have tried restarting all the main exchange services.

Just added an email account, via the pop3 connector. It downloaded email to an account without any problems at all.

Comment: I've had a similar problem with Exchange 2010 and users for who I changed the Display Name. Not a persistent problem though, since after some time (a day or so) the bodies of the emails reappeared. Highly annoying and have not found any real explanation why this happens. I'd look for possible explanations at [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com). YMMV

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by Watchguard firewall, disabling the firewall restore normal Email delivery.